# How can I use nextjs to create static website with SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, next.js, next.js13, getstaticprops, generatestaticparams

My name is usman and I am new here I have a question.

I am currently working on a website that I plan to build using Next.js. This website will showcase over 100 poems from a renowned poet, all stored in an SQLite database. My objective is to retrieve this data from the database and present it on the website through cards or lists.

However, I am encountering an issue where the page requests data from the SQLite database every time it is refreshed, which I recognize as an inefficient approach. Since the content is static and won't change frequently, I attempted to utilize functions like `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` to fetch data from the SQLite database during build time. Unfortunately, I'm facing difficulties with this implementation, and I would greatly appreciate your assistance. If my question is unclear or if you need further clarification, please let me know.

I tried them but there is no specific documentation of about this.